# Использование yandex.metrika при добавлении в корзину через AJAX

Tags: yandex-metrika-api, ecommerce

Пытаюсь настроить Yandex.metrika  с электронной коммерцией.

Успешно сделал учет просмотра товаров. Теперь на Метрике у меня показываются популярные товары, категории, бренды - т.е. счетчик установлен правильно!  Все круто.

Но уткнулся в проблему учета добавленных в корзину товаров.
Дело в том, что добавление в корзину сделано через AJAX. Т.е. понятно, что нужно `dataLayer.push({})` вставлять в ответ AJAX, но почему-то не срабатывает.

AJAX выглядит так:

```
function addToCart(itemID, el) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: aPath,
    data: 'do=addToCart&itemID=' + itemID,
    success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        /* ecommerce push for yandex metrika */
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'addToCart',
            "ecommerce": {
                'currencyCode': 'RUB',
                "add": {
                    "products": [{
                        "id": itemID,
                        "name": data.name,
                        "price": data.price,
                        "brand": data.brand,
                        "category": data.category,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "variant" : data.variant
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    },
    dataType:'json'
});
```

`console.log(data);` выдает в консоль всю необходимую информацию... Все, что дожно происходить на сайте при добавлении в корзину происходит как надо... вот только Метрика не хочет: в статистике метрики ничего не появляется...

Любые предположения принимаются!

Answer (score 1):

а просмотр у вас как реализован? мне кажется, надо поставить выше эту строку
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];